# Validate NumberField's value, not length

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

### `Model`:

```
Ext.define('Web.model.Server', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty : 'guid',

    fields : [ {
        name : 'guid',
        type : 'string'
    },/* ... */ {
        name : 'timeout',
        type : 'integer'
    }],

    validators : {
        timeout : {
            type : 'length',
            min : 10,
            max : 60
        }
    }
});
```

Whenever I set `timeout` to any value (such as `40`) and call `.isValid()`, it returns `false` and says `timeout: Length must be between 10 and 60`. In other words, it is validating the value's length as a `String`, not the value of the number itself.

I can't find anything in the documentation about validating number's values: the [5.1.1 ext validator docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.validator.Validator) are not extensively written.

How can I validate the value of the number, instead of its length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [range validator](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.validator.Range):

```
validators: {
    timeout: {
        type: 'range',
        min: 10,
        max: 60
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect and simple. I must have missed this one. It works.